# Mysterious OLPC stuff in Wireshark 802.11 disssector

Tags: wireshark, wifi

I ran into a 802.11 packet, which Wireshark dissects successfully, but I don't understand the meaning and justification of the "Mysterious OLPC Stuff".

[image: Wireshark Capture]

I also found the following discussion which led to this Wireshark feature, but the justification remains unclear:

https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2313